# ExtJS 6 plugin.rowwidget Get binded record upon row body component creation

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I have a grid with [Ext.grid.plugin.RowWidget](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.plugin.RowWidget.html). When I expand row I have to load some data via ajax using row record data as request parameters and display loaded data in a row body component.

How I can get row record data upon row body component creation? I've tried `initComponent` and `afterrender` listener, but I understand that it is not appropriate place because data is not binded yet. I have to listen for another event or?

Here is [simple fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1t1q) illustrating my problem and what I've tried already.

Comment: Use `onWidgetAttach` on the RowWidget plugin itself. That is the correct timing for when the record is attached to the component.

Comment: @evan-trimboli Thanks! Btw, I cant find this widget property in documentation... Am I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Evan Trimboli, `onWidgetAttach` seems to work:

```
        plugins: [{
            ptype: 'rowwidget',
            widget: {
                xtype: 'characterPanel',
                bind: {
                    characterName: '{record.name}'
                },
            },
            onWidgetAttach: function (plugin, bodyComponent, record) {
                // Do stuff
            }
        }],
```

Check [updated fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1t1q).