# ExtJS 6 plugin.rowwidget Row body component persist on grid reload

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I have a grid with [Ext.grid.plugin.RowWidget](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.plugin.RowWidget.html). When grid store reloaded I expect all row body components to be recreated, but they remains.

Here is [simple fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1tgg), to repeat the bug:

1. Expand first row;
2. Change value of any textfield;
3. Click 'Reload' button;
4. Expand first row.

I expect new `Ext.CharacterPanel` instance with empty fields as row body component...

*It's a huge bug imo.*

As temporary solution I can reset row body component on [`expandbody`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.plugin.RowWidget.html#event-expandbody) event or with [`onWidgetAttach`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43093599/2667065) method, but it seems like bad solution for me.